# Why is onchange event not firing on first change?

Tags: javascript, html, events, onchange

Thank you for taking the time for reading my question.

A "range" `input` element in HTML (Slider) fires an `onchange` -event, in which the content of a `span` element gets updated with the current value of the `input` element.

Somehow, the first change made to the `input` element doesn't fire the `onchange` event. When an 'onclick' event is used, it does fire.

Here's the code, HTML first:

```
<div>

    <input id="main_options_plug1_lengthPE_input" type="range" step="10" value="0" max="200" min="0" onchange="setOpenEndPELength('plug1');"></input>
    <span id="main_options_plug1_lengthPE_value"> … </span>

</div>
```

And now JavaScript:

```
function setOpenEndPELength(plug)
{
    if (plug == "plug1" || plug == "plug2")
    {
        var slider = document.getElementById("main_options_" + plug + "_lengthPE_input");
        var span = document.getElementById("main_options_" + plug + "_lengthPE_value");

        span.innerHTML = slider.value + " mm";
    }
}
```

I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Md8f/2/), so you can try it yourself.

I didn't find an answer to this question on stackoverflow so far, any questions i found were about `onchange` event don't firing at all. In this case, it's only the first change that doesn't work.

Hope someone knows the answer. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: The fiddle works as expected for me, but it's a bit hard to understand when it doesn't work (what does "It does an onclick event is used, it does fire" mean?)

Comment: Are you actually changing the value or just clicking on it? What browser does the problem occur in?

Comment: @Juhana: I corrected it so it makes sense now. Sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: Its working as expected.

Comment: @epascarello: the button on the slider is in another position than it is at the start, so i assume it is a change. I'm using Mozilla Firefox 25.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the problem is that on Firefox, the `onchange` handler is not executed when you press down mouse button when the cursor is on the button of the slider and move the mouse. It is executed only after you release the mouse button after such a move.

This seems to be the correct behavior (though some other browsers don’t comply), since HTML5 CR says about the [`change` event](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#event-input-change): “if the element does not have an activation behavior defined but uses a user interface that involves an explicit commit action, then any time the user commits a change to the element's value or list of selected files, the user agent must queue a task to fire a simple event that bubbles named change at the input element.”

That’s a bit complicated formulation, but it is followed by a clarifying example: “A third example of a user interface with a commit action would be a Range controls that use a slider. While the user is dragging the control's knob, input events would fire whenever the position changed, whereas the change event would only fire when the user let go of the knob, committing to a specific value.”

The conclusion is that in this case, you should use the `oninput` attribute instead of `onchange`. In practice, `onmousemove` works too, but `oninput` is better, since it can be expected to work with input methods that do not use a mouse (whatever they might be, e.g. control by voice).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I think i have a different problem. When i drag the slider to a different position then the `onchange` event fires on the first change. If I only click on a different position, the control knob's position changes but the onchange event doesnt fire.

Comment: I see; it’s an odd phenomenon. Using `oninput` instead of `onchange` fixes that problem, too.

Answer (score 2):

On document ready try to trigger event manually caused first time change is not occurred.

So just add code as below:

```
$(“#main_options_plug1_lengthPE_input”).trigger(‘change’)
```

Answer (score -1):

A little trick, if onchange doesn't fire the first time, add:

```
onclick="console.log(1)"
```

Some other action on the click, it still fire the onchange as second time but as first you have the click.